# Resizing shelf icons to fit its space

Tags: icons, maya, mel

I have created two shelf buttons and icons but in the image attachment I have put up, you can see that the yellow icon seems to be working correctly but as for the blue icon, it is sticking to the top-left hand corner of its 'space'

The initial sizing I have created for the yellow icon is 32 x 32 pixels while the blue one is 20 x 20 pixels

Both shelf attributes are pretty much the same but I am unable to get the blue icon to either match in size or have it be in the center.

Thus are there any other ways in which I can resize it, have it in a reasonable sizing like the yellow one without creating another new image to 32 x 32 pixels?

```
// -------- 32 x 32 pixels --------
shelfButton
    -enableCommandRepeat 0
    -enable 1
    -width 34
    -height 34
    -manage 1
    -visible 1
    -label "Yellow Icon"
    -image "icon_yellow.png"
    -style "iconOnly"
    ;

// -------- 20 x 20 pixels --------
shelfButton
    -enableCommandRepeat 0
    -enable 1
    -width 34
    -height 34
    -manage 1
    -visible 1
    -label "Blue Icon"
    -image1 "icon_blue.png"
    -style "iconOnly"
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove -label flag and add -scaleIcon and iconAndTextHorizontal style.
Tested on the 2016 version.

```
// -------- 20 x 20 pixels --------
shelfButton
    -enableCommandRepeat 0
    -enable 1
    -width 34
    -height 34
    -manage 1
    -visible 1
    -image1 "icon_blue.png"
    -scaleIcon // scale
    -style "iconAndTextHorizontal"// need for scale
;
```

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/ff5b398b3ea5de3b11e404565059e4b8.png]

Comment: thanks for getting back, unfortunately I am not using Maya 2016 and there is no such `scaleIcon` flag, possibly this is meant for the new version? Even so, I have managed to resolve the current problem I have initially by redoing the size. Thanks again for the help!